# Reference request on vector sheaves

Tags: reference-request, sheaf-theory

I wanted to study the book "Geometry of vector sheaves", by Anastasios Mallios. I only found the second volume, but I cannot find the first anywhere. Is there a reference for the general theory vector sheaves?

Thank you

Comment: https://www.amazon.co.uk/gp/product/0792350049/

Comment: Thanks, but is there something like lecture notes? I really need only the basic definitions